# Needing Code For ExtJS 4 renderer for checkbox column in Ext.Grid.Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've been wrestling with how to make the column show as a checkbox (non-editable one).

Any Suggested code for the renderer? Seems like there should be a simple config option, but I can't find it.

```
 Ext.define('AEDT.view.EmailListByAddressEntry', {
     extend: 'AEDT.view.ui.EmailListByAddressEntry',
     alias: 'widget.emaillistbyaddressentry',

     initComponent: function () {
         var me = this;
         me.callParent(arguments);
     },

     onCheckBoxWhilteListOnlyChange: function (field, newValue, oldValue, options) {
         //debugger
         if (newValue) {

             this.store.filter("WhiteList", true);
             store.filter();
         } else {
             this.store.clearFilter();
         }
     },
     onBooleancolumnRender: function (abstractcomponent, options) {

     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your comment on the `Ext.grid.column.Boolean` page. Anyway, the description of the `renderer` config states that the return value is "a HTML string to be rendered". So it seems to me that the following should work (simplified for brevity):

```
renderer: function(value) {
    var text = '<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"';
    if(value) {
        text += ' checked="checked"';
    }
    return text + '/>';
}
```

Comment: overriding this is a simplest way to disable specific checkbox based on other fields of record. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the checkbox plugin?

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid/grid-plugins.html